# Worst case error for a DAC

Tags: dac, error

I am trying to estimate the worst case absolute error for a DAC (the example I'm taking is MAXIM MX7524). I'm getting familiar with the concepts of INL, DNL,... But how would you estimate the worst case error? What errors need to be accounted in a cumulative manner?

Additional info:

After some further research I have found [this](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2013/10/09/dac-essentials-how-accurate-is-your-dac) website. I tried to compute the error for [this](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/M/A/X/7/MAX7524.shtml) DAC and for me it would go like:
$$TUE = \pm \sqrt{(0.5)^2 + (3.5)^2 + 1^2} \approx \pm 3.7 LSB$$
Where the maximal values used are: relative accuracy = 1/2 LSB, Diff non lin = 1 LSB, gain error = 3.5 LSB
Am I doing it in the right way?

Is it in general a large error or I can find better DAC?

Comment: All of them....

Comment: I just found this: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2013/10/09/dac-essentials-how-accurate-is-your-dac, is that a wrong way of estimating the total error?

Answer (score 1):

[That](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2013/10/09/dac-essentials-how-accurate-is-your-dac) article seems fine but you also have to consider temperature effects if not being held constant at one temperature. For instance there will be a gain error temperature coefficient and this might be 20 ppm / degC meaning that if there is a change in temeperature of 30 degC there could be a further error in the gain of 600 ppm (parts per million) or 0.06%.

Same applies to the offset error and you need to ensure that INL is specified to be a max value within the temperature range you are expecting. Don't forget to consider local heating effects on your circuit from (say) linear regulators - they will warm things up a bit more.

Comment: Do you understand why the article says that: "DNL, meanwhile, is actually included in the error calculation via INL". That's quite wired since in my case DNL +/-1 LSB and INL +/- 1/2 LSB.

Comment: I suspect that the authour may be assuming that DNL is a fraction of INL and it's not really worth adding this bit in. In your case DNL is bigger than INL so it certainly should be accounted for.

Comment: BTW I think your DAC is a max5714 and not a 7514!

Comment: No actually it is MX 5724, sorry about that! Could the offset error be called supply rejection? Or they are completely different things? Thanks I thought the same for the DNL and INL.

Comment: Is it possible that I get something like +/- 3.5LSB?

Comment: Show your working as to how you got +/-3.5 LSB. I'm not saying you are wrong I'm being lazy! Put it in your question as a supplement would be a good idea because you are extending the reach of the question by a little (but not too much) and it might be useful for other folk to see this.

Comment: TUE is an RMS value of error - absolute discrepancy of the error is the peak of this value but you can't say it is \$\sqrt2\$ higher like in a sinewave. If you want to know the instantaneous error at any one point in time you have to add up all the worst case values. This may be more important than the RMS TUE and yes, I'd consider putting DNL in the equation like you did.

Comment: I was wondering why he was using the root... Naturally I would have added them... Do you know if this is a typical value... It looks quite large to me!!!

Comment: Note that the article refers to 3 sigma - this is a measn of calculating the instantaneous error from the RMS TUE figure. A comparison is "converting" an RMS noise to a p-p noise - 6 sigma is used i.e. 1mV RMS becomes 6 mVp-p - but this (as per TUE) relies on a gaussian distribution of noise or errors. Maybe you are digging a hole too deep - maybe just consider addding all the worst case elements together?

Comment: Adding the worst case would give 3.5+0.5+1 = 5 LSB... It looks huge to me

Comment: A 12 bit dac has over 4000 to 1 resolution and 5 lsbs represents an error of 5 in 4000 or about 0.1%. Is this that large?

Comment: No not for a 12 bit DAC, but the one I need is a 8 bit DAC.

Comment: In that case, the worst case error could be 5 bits in 256 bits = ~2% BUT, it all depends what you are using this device for as to whether this is significant or not - I see it is a multiplying DAC so are you using it as some kind of gain control - if so then it is of little consequence to audio. Other applications might easily be offended by such a specification.

Comment: I need a DAC to convert a digital control signal of 8 bits into a 0 to 5 volts to control a pressure regulator... And to be honest I don't know what DAC would be best for this application

Comment: Choose a higher resolution dac that has the same performance as the 8 bit dac but is maybe 12 bit and therefore the errors dwarf into insignificance. There are many.

Comment: I had the same idea, use a 16 bit DAC with +/- Vref of +\-5V... The problem is that I do not have any -5V... At the same time I could simply invert the +5 with a NOT right?

Comment: Broaden your horizons to what dacs are available is my advice.

Comment: There is a really nice application note for a true precision device at http://www.linear.com/docs/4177